# Using choose with cors in policy fragments

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to use the CORS APIM policy inside a choose statement?

I have a policy fragment that roughly looks like:

```
    <choose>
        <when condition=".....">
            <cors allow-credentials="false">
                <allowed-origins>
                     ......
                </allowed-origins>
            </cors>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <cors allow-credentials="false">
                <allowed-origins>
                     ......
                </allowed-origins>
            </cors>
            .....
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
```

However, when I try to save, I get:

`Error in element 'cors' on line xx, column xx: Only one policy statement of this type is allowed per section`

I'd expect to be able to use  to choose between CORS environments in the fragment, based on some environment or named value. Not possible?

Answer (score 0):

**There can only be one [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/cors-policy)-type policy statement per section, according to the Azure API Management policy guide**. Thus, as you have suggested, **you cannot** utilise the CORS policy inside a choose statement. To set the backend service dynamically based on a condition, **you can use the [set-backend-service policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-backend-service-policy),after that you can apply the CORS policy to the backend service**.

Below is the sample set backend policy,

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="...">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://backend1.example.com" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://backend2.example.com" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <cors allow-credentials="false">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>https://example.com</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

Reference MS [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-cors-error-in-azure-api-management-service/ba-p/2241695).